# Algorithm for getting random parts

Tags: algorithm

I need to find algorithm for generate 3 random numbers, but for the following conditions to hold true:

1) `|part1| +|part2|+|part3|=< SumConst`, where SumConst is even number and SumConst is not big number (`0< SumConst< 13`)

2) for each part `-1*SumConst=< part =< SumConst`

3) `part1 +part2+part3=0`

Some examples:

```
SumConst=2

-1,1,0; 

SumConst=10

-5,5,0 ; -2,-3,5; -4,-1,5 ...
```

Comment: Generate random numbers until they fit the condition? (Or generate first two randomly, and derive the third from the second condition.) If you write some "special" random number algorithms, they probably won't be very random.

Comment: Condition 3 is very strong. In fact, you have only two random numbers, the third one is then determined.

Comment: Since you're very constrained, you could just make a table of possibilities for each `sumConst`. Then pick a random one of those.

Comment: @Geobits, i thiniking about this method. Do you know algorithm for getting table of possible numbers ?

Comment: to generate the table of possibilities, just write 2 nested loops

Comment: Thanks all!! Will try to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your conditions are very limiting, it might be easier to generate a table of all all valid possibilities for a given `sumConst`. You can then pick a random one of these easily. It would be faster for each lookup, at the trade of some preprocessing and a bit of space.

Pseudocode to generate list (not checked for errors, just a general idea):

```
for a = -sumConst to sumConst
    bMax = sumConst - |a|
    for b = -bMax to bMax
        c = -a - b
        if |a| + |b| + |c| <= sumConst
            add (a,b,c) to list
```